# Counting recrusive function in IA86 assembly - unexpected values

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, intel-syntax

I've wrote assembly program which should count the below recursive function :

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) - f(n-3)
```

For n = 0 and n = 1 it returns 1, and for n = 2  it should return 0.
But for this values program always returns 0, it looks like the below conditions were never met.

```
if0:              
  mov eax,1
  jmp end
if1:               
  mov eax,1
  jmp end          
if2:               
  mov eax,0
  jmp end
```

For any other value (greater than 2) I recives an segmentation falut.
Below is the entire code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl main
.text

main:

  mov eax, 3

  push eax
  call f

  push eax
  push offset msg
  call printf
  add esp, 8

  mov eax, 0
  ret

f:
  push    ebp        
  mov     ebp,esp   
  add     ebp,12     
  mov     ebx,[ebp]   

  cmp     ebx, 0      
  jz     if0
  cmp     ebx, 1
  jz     if1
  cmp     ebx, 2
  jz     if2

  lea ecx, [ebx-1]
  push ecx            
  call  f             
  pop ecx            

  push eax            
  lea ecx,[2*ebx-2]
  push ecx           
  call  f            
  pop ecx             
  pop eax         
  add eax,ecx        

  push eax
  lea ecx, [ebx-3]
  push ecx            
  call f             
  pop ecx             
  pop eax             
  sub eax,ecx
  jmp end

if0:              
  mov eax,1
  jmp end
if1:               
  mov eax,1
  jmp end          
if2:               
  mov eax,0
  jmp end         

end:
  pop     ebx         
  pop     ebp         
  ret

msg:    .asciz "Output = %d\n"
```

I have no idea what I do wrong.
EDIT: So, I've experimented with ebp and I've changed 
    add ebp,8 
to:
    add ebp, 16.
And, now it works for base conditions. It seems to me that there is problem with stack overflow, but I don't see it where is it.

Comment: What do you expect the processor to do once it has executed `if0:  
  mov eax,1`?

Comment: Move 1 to eax when ebx is equal 0 or 1, eax is the register which store the result.

Comment: Read my question again. *What* **do** *you* **expect** the processor *to* do once **it has executed `if0: mov eax,1`**?

Comment: Sorry, I don't catch it I see my fault I want to stop executing program. I see that i shoudl add here `jmp end`.

Comment: Now that you changed the code in your question, does it still fail?

Comment: Yes. But when I changet  `add esp, 8` to ` add esp, 16` it gives good results for base conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pop ebx` has no corresponding `push`, messing up your stack. There could well be other errors, but that's the one that jumped out at me.

Comment: Unfortunatley this don't sovle the problem at all, even though it looks like you were right.